# Getting application title from a Word OLE application object

Tags: delphi, winapi, ms-word, ole

Is there a way of getting the window title from a Word.Application OLE object? I'd like to use it to try get the window using `FindWindow`.

I'm creating an OLE object and adding an existing document, like so:

```
App := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');
App.Visible := True;
App.Activate;
Doc := App.Documents.Open('File.doc');
```

At this point, the caption values are the following:

```
App.Caption => 'Microsoft Word'
Doc.ActiveWindow.Caption => 'File.doc [Compatibility Mode]'
```

However, the window title is actually `File.doc [Compatibility Mode] - Microsoft Word`.

Is there some way of getting this window title from the OLE object (there does not seem to be a better way of getting the HWND itself without using `FindWindow`)? I doubt it is safe to assume the window title will always be `<doc caption> - <app caption>`.

I'd like to use the `FindWindow` function to get a handle to the window to be able to bring it to the foreground (see [OLE Automation to launch MS Word and bring to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860250/ole-automation-to-launch-ms-word-and-bring-to-front)) in a slightly safer manner by passing in the correct title.

**EDIT**

Here's the fix using the workaround described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258511

```
App := CreateOLEObject('Word.Application');

// get the handle
TempTitle := 'Temp - ' + IntToStr(Random(1000000));
App.Caption := TempTitle;
Handle := FindWindow('OpusApp', PWideChar(TempTitle));
App.Caption := EmptyStr;

App.Visible := True;
App.Activate;
Doc := App.Documents.Open('File.doc');

// bring to front
SetForegroundWindow(Handle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[How to obtain the window handle for an Office Automation server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258511)

Comment: Please add a short description of what the article behind the link is about. It increases the general usability of StackOverflow.

Comment: Yep, the workaround in the "Find the Window Handle for an Application That Can Have Multiple Instances" worked.

I get the handle by randomizing a temporary application caption using the method described and then use it to bring the window to the foreground later.

Comment: @Marjan - I added the title of the KB article, hope that helps.