# How to query display name of an embedded OLE application

Tags: excel, delphi, ms-word, ole

I would like to query the display name of an OLE application, which is embedded in my Delphi XE4 Win32 app.

`TOleContainer` class is used and the container can contain different OLE applications (e.g. *MS Word*, *MS Excel*, ...), dependent on what file is edited within.

What I want to be returned is *Microsoft Word 2007* (or 2010 or 2013 or ...) or at least *Microsoft Word*, as it is displayed in the title bar of a normal Word instance.

---

**EDIT:**
TOndrej's answer was very helpful. Thank you.

Unfortunally, as described in my comment underneath his answer, it does not show the real application caption. I found this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7652171/4236400). It's said there, that I could access the host application's caption with `_Application.Caption` property. I don't have an instance of `_Application` but `IOleObject`. Typecast (`MyOleObjectInterface as _Application`) failed.

How can the OleObject be accessed as `_Application`?

Comment: What is `_Application`? It's not an interface type that I recognise.

Comment: @David You can find it in units `Excel2010` and `Word2010` in Delphi XE4, for example.

Comment: There's not a single application interface that all interfaces derive from or support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`IOleObject.GetUserType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method:

```
function GetOleObjectAppName(const OleObject: IOleObject): string;
var
  AppName: PWideChar;
begin
  OleCheck(OleObject.GetUserType(USERCLASSTYPE_APPNAME, AppName));
  try
    Result := AppName;
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(AppName);
  end;
end;
```

Usage example:

```
  ShowMessage(GetOleObjectAppName(OleContainer1.OleObjectInterface));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But: It seems to return the name based on the current file format. For example, it returns *Microsoft Excel 2003* for a Excel97-2003 file, although Microsoft Office 2007 is installed. Is there a way to avoid that and return the name of the actual handler?

Comment: btw: is `try..finally` used correctly here? If `OleCheck` raises an exception, memory for `AppName` wouldn't be freed, right?

Comment: @RenéHoffmann Yes and that's the correct usage. If `Olecheck` raises an exception nothing is allocated, nothing is freed.

Comment: Perhaps you could start with [`IOleObject.GetUserClassID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682313(v=vs.85).aspx) instead and look up the application name in the [registry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1265/COM-IDs-Registry-keys-in-a-nutshell), (possibly via `AppID`).